# Android startActivity not working

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I'm having small problem with my app. `startActivity(Intent intent)` is not working.

```
    switch (id) {
        case R.id.action_add:
            if (auth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
                if (vf.getDisplayedChild() > 0 && vf.getDisplayedChild() < 3) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SubmitActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("category", vf.getDisplayedChild());
                    startActivity(intent);
                    Toast.makeText(this, "You are about to create record", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
            break;
        case R.id.action_save:
            saveList("monuments", monument_data);
            saveList("ski_resorts", ski_data);
            Toast.makeText(this, "Data saved for offline use", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
    }
```

Actually, someone should simply tell that statement's condition wasn't meeted but in fact, toast after `startActivity` is shown so statement is correct. I have intent also in recyclerview's adapter on `framelayout` is clicked but here intent doesn't work also.

I could also mention that I have intent with shared object animation(not the same intent).

Anyone knows what is wrong? Intent in switch statement(shown above) worked until I added intent into recyclerview, Please help.

EditActivity:

```
public class EditActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

FirebaseAuth auth;
DatabaseReference ref, target;
StorageReference storage;

ProgressDialog dialog;

@BindView(R.id.imageView8)
ImageView main_image;
@BindView(R.id.input_title)
EditText title;
@BindView(R.id.input_desc)
EditText desc;
@BindView(R.id.input_location)
EditText location;
@BindView(R.id.switch1)
Switch isPublic;
@BindView(R.id.switch2)
Switch isFree;
@BindView(R.id.input_price)
EditText price;
@BindView(R.id.button3)
Button send;

public static final int PICK_IMAGE = 1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit);
    ButterKnife.bind(this); . . . }}
```

SubmitActivity:

```
public class SubmitActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

FirebaseAuth auth;
DatabaseReference ref, target;
StorageReference storage;

ProgressDialog dialog;

@BindView(R.id.imageView8)
ImageView main_image;
@BindView(R.id.input_title)
EditText title;
@BindView(R.id.input_desc)
EditText desc;
@BindView(R.id.input_location)
EditText location;
@BindView(R.id.switch1)
Switch isPublic;
@BindView(R.id.switch2)
Switch isFree;
@BindView(R.id.input_price)
EditText price;
@BindView(R.id.button3)
Button send;

public static final int PICK_IMAGE = 1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_submit);
    ButterKnife.bind(this); . . . }}
```

This part filtered with "intent" appear when option is selected:

> 01-11 18:37:13.918 22224-22239/? I/ActivityManager: START u0 {flg=0x8000 cmp=com.ready.slovakia/.SubmitActivity (has extras)} from uid 10883 on display 0
>    01-11 18:37:14.122 22224-22251/? I/WindowManager: Gaining focus: Window{8f13679 u0 com.ready.slovakia/com.ready.slovakia.MainActivity}

Comment: Please explain what "not working" means to you

Comment: Did you try to debug that statement by adding a breakpoint?

Comment: @KartikArora yes, as mentioned, toast is shown

Comment: @GoCrafter_LP Need more description on what's not working here. Why did you expect and what is happening?

Comment: @KartikArora activity is not called, just nothing happens. Toast is shown, in console no error or warning, but just activity is not opened

Comment: @KartikArora in recyclerview I have also intent calling activity and it do same... all is did on click but activity is not shown

Comment: Mind sharing the full project here so that it can be tested?

Comment: @KartikArora https://github.com/gocrafterlp/Slovakia

Comment: @KartikArora I have added into post 2 lines from LogCat that appear and contains SubmitActivity when option is selected. It means that intent is called.

Comment: @GoCrafter_LP, I've just cloned your repo, will have a look now.

Comment: @KartikArora gradle tool will probably throw error because I had defined keystore passwords etc. in file "keystore.properties" that I excluded from repo

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163003/discussion-between-gocrafter-lp-and-kartik-arora).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per our discussion on chat and the debugging, here's the issue:

You `SubmitActivity.java` has `if (auth.getCurrentUser() != null) finish();` on line 78, which finishes the activity when the user is authenticated and logged in. It should be `if (auth.getCurrentUser() == null) finish();` instead.

But ideally, this issue will not arise because you are checking the same condition on line 390 of `MainActivity.java`, which will prevent intent from getting `SubmitActivity` started when the user is not logged in.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your layout in the `SubmitActivity`. Do you set the content via: `setContentView()` ? Most probably your activity is started but nothing is displayed so it's invisible.